# Cascading Parameters Refresh in SSRS Report for Date Selection

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-expression, ssrs-2014

I'm using SSRS report.

How to set another parameters default date based on first selected date. Please see the below image.

[image]

Here, when I will select Date value as `02-01-16` I wanted to add 14days to this date and then I want to set this updated date to **`Start Date`** parameter.

How can I do this? Can anyone please help me.

**Note:** *So I want the same behavior like onchange event.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Yes!* *I found the easy solution.*

We need to create different `Dataset`. let's say I have created Dataset 
**`AddDaysDs`**.

***AddDaysDs Dataset***

```
SELECT DATEADD(dd ,14 ,@SelectdDate) AS StartDate
```

Inside `Dataset`, pass **`SelectdDate`** as a parameter to get **`StartDate`**.

Now, *Right click* on **`StartDate`** parameter and then goto ***Parameter properties*** then inside ***Available values*** tick **Get values from a query** and set dataset **`AddDaysDs`**

Same thing do inside **`Default Values`** of the same field.

***Note: Ensure that all two parameters `Advanced` property must ticked as `Always refresh`***

Comment: Now it did not show the calendar icon while populating `StartDate` - Does anyone have any idea to do this?

Comment: try remove everything in "Available Values"

Comment: I tried. But then it will update the `StartDate` only for first time. :(

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a new dataset with this query

   @ParamDate <-- is your selected Date Parameter's Name.
   *select DATEADD(dd,14,@ParamDate) as NewDate*
2. Right click your "Start Date" parameter 

   => Default Values 

   => Select "Get Values from a query" 

   => Select dataset created in (1) 

   => Value Field: NewDate.
   [image]
3. Done.
   [image]

Comment: Good answer! but it will directly come up with selecting `added days` - what I want is if user select `Param Date :` then it should refresh the second date again. how can I do this? (like onchange event behavior)

Comment: you can refer step(2) and do it under "Available Values", is that what you want ?  Can't really understand "then it should refresh the second date again", what is the second date?

Comment: not possible... still facing same issue. any other way I can achieve this?

Comment: I don't think anyway can achieve like onchange event in ssrs default control, unless you use this report as local report, and do it from your web application.